# How to edit and print a word or pdf document using C#.net?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a huge collection of database of my customers in MS access. I have made a custom mail (print mail) formats. In each format, I've generated separate fields for each dynamic field.

Example:

```
 __________________
|                  | 
|                  |
|      LOGO        |
|      IMAGE       |
|                  |
 __________________

=====================================================

Dear %customername%,
      Your age is %age%. bla bla bla..

Thank you!
```

I want to programtically detect %customername% field and fill it with each name from the database and finally print it.

How can i accomplish this without using any external libraries in C#.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into microsoft reporting services SSRS, that is exactly what you need. Microsoft provides a free .NET library for SSRS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need the **[String.Replace Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)**

```
string customername = "Paul Jones";
completeText = completeText.Replace("%customername%", customername);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Carspar's answer is the simplest method that would work, although one would probably not use string if you have to do a lot of replacements of a large amount of text. Another built-in library that may be of interest is using [Razor](http://kazimanzurrashid.com/posts/use-razor-for-email-template-outside-asp-dot-net-mvc) library from ASP.NET MVC 3. There are some external libraries built on top if you don't mind use 3rd party assemblies. http://razorengine.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Detecting any variable field that starts and ends with % can be done using a regular expression. With regular expressions you can easily find the name within the % block.

[Regular expression information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30wbz966%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Having the name you can match that to a database field and replace the value using string.Replace() or the regex.Replace() functions.